# Flutter: Firebase Streambuilder returning a null value

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have a problem with getting data from the firestore in flutter. when I run the app it print out('not okay') so that means I'm get null data from Firebase. i still don't understand.i have done some google searches  but it didn't help.i tried with few ways.i think something wrong with `stream: DatabaseService().schedulesData,` that part.

```
class _DashboardState extends State<Dashboard> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final UserData userData = widget.userData;
    return StreamBuilder<SchedulesData>(
        stream: DatabaseService().schedulesData,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            print('okay');
          } else {
            print('not okay');
          }
          return Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 30),
                        child: Icon(
                          Icons.add,
                          size: 60,
                          color: Color(0xFF34495e),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          );
        });
  }
}
```

here is the model class:

```
class DatabaseService {
 // Schedules data from snapshots
  SchedulesData _schedulesDataFromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snapshot) {
    return SchedulesData(
      destination: snapshot.data['destination'],
      active: snapshot.data['active'],
      duration: snapshot.data['duration'],
    );
  }

  Stream<SchedulesData> get schedulesData {
    return Firestore.instance
        .collection('schedules')
        .document('8AAqdgV36T3utTSyLc9d')
        .snapshots()
        .map(_schedulesDataFromSnapshot);
  }
}
```

see the image here
[image: Heres the image of tha database]

Comment: Add a screenshot of your database

Comment: I have add the image of database

Comment: @Peter Haddad what's the solution for this?

Comment: i don't see a single await

Comment: Are you sure your document name is the same as the one in cloud-firestore?

Comment: Yaa. name was same  i tried with other documents also but didn't work out.

Comment: Does anyone got any idea. Why this not working?

Comment: It should be working, I don't see anything wrong with your code. Are you getting any other sort of output in the console?